# Bash read file and get values from to

Tags: bash, shell

Any idea how to read a file and get text from to values?

Let´s say I have

```
    Json info lastActiveTimes:{"707514313":1505584723,"100004389551456":1505591385},chatNotif:0}, a lot of more Json info.
```

And I want to get from Start: to End, so read the file and just return

```
{"707514313":1505584723,"100004389551456":1505591385}
```

I´m using bash from OSX

Comment: You are much better served using the `jq` (json query) package to parse json. (as you can see by additional json info before your example causing problems). That said, `sed` or `grep` for that matter with PCRE can handle retrieving the contents of the braces.

Comment: Thanks I know jq, but I´m afraid this source is not only json but html as well.

Comment: [OP comments indicate there's more than one json bracket block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258581/bash-read-file-and-get-values-from-to#comment79486880_46258713), (*i.e.*: `{...}`), therefore this question is vague, and needs to specify which bracket block is desired.

Answer (score 2):

When you have `2nd line with start in it` between Start and End, you can use

```
sed -n '/Start:/,/End/p' file| sed '1s/.*Start://; $s/End.*//'
```

UPDATE:
Question has changed,now it can be anything like

```
sed 's/.*\({[^}]*}\).*/\1/' file
```

of

```
grep -Eo "{[^}]*}" file
```

Comment: Not able to make it works, gave me an grep command error, I update my question with the real data now. Thanks

Comment: Not working because there are Json info before and after the example that I paste. I update my question, sorry to do not create clear in the first place.

Comment: I see you accepted an answer to your similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/46262713/3220113 so I think you can solve remaining issues yourself.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep and [Perl regular expression](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) (`-P`):

```
grep -Poz '(?<=Start:).*(\n)*.*(?= End)' file
```

Output:

```
aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbb
ccccccc
```

Comment: Not able to make it works, gave me an grep command error, I update my question with the real data now. Thanks

Comment: I dont have Perl regular expresion, any idea how to do it without it?