# Read file until match pattern

Tags: bash, shell

I´m reading a file and I would like to get the info until I found a match.

So having the file here https://ufile.io/182kx

I would like to have the json info from lastActiveTimes: until I found ,chatNotif:0

Returning

```
{"707514313":1505610703,"1568212945":1505638160,"732898933":1505638352,"100009336847960":1505635266,"721251435":1505570865,"718844397":1505623246,"1461941075":1505501435,"100004389551456":1505637706,"1211838231":1505582601,"1040249145":1505636186,"1242203773":1505628782,"517814298":1505567030,"807572767":1505638353,"738307936":1505638009,"683874946":1505598251,"822469152":1505636589,"727476234":1505627000,"781209703":1505631577,"1058918804":1505629365,"539657070":1505629599,"1506662943":1505606109,"538279690":1505575467,"1122078957":1505633239,"1426504238":1505614371,"1760126206":1505637897,"100009494169236":1505633218,"100000193088625":1505633785,"628050112":1505599301,"692803720":1505602132,"100000982526361":1505611187,"1567918281":1505549275,"562061542":1505633121,"680188549":1505637979,"201400626":1505510516,"709905371":1505635235,"100000921265645":1505637511,"100002576634271":1505633420,"100001152648289":1505638358,"1580474418":1505583268,"1093906498":1505635647,"1568491642":1505613600,"1759941492":1505592915,"1021502749":1505621933,"100001091369712":1505593740,"1201111516":1505631603,"511729394":1505637150,"1228064980":1505627119,"1484357891":1505632720,"773982263":1505636776,"610763631":1505581711,"581839860":1505636663,"100001509228647":1505550106,"100001496847848":1505520708,"553024640":1505631903,"1657607627":1505460838,"100008134920032":1505636261,"518105631":1505610763,"100000167522595":1505559871,"604094302":1505591423,"831534764":1505498705,"716402163":1505625063,"100005862197805":1505615273,"779160397":1505625381,"683029723":1505602056,"1105801871":1505638150,"1007323327":1505618323,"500432034":1505617899,"1019441248":1505593648,"1321064988":1505549642,"600465009":1505557526,"734790522":1505614982,"1139898038":1505597330,"762749332":1505595541,"100006926654236":1505637009,"100007887856728":1505580453,"1073032118":1505602788,"575893114":1505630287,"1463373342":1505609305}
```

I was trying sed with

```
sed -n '/lastActiveTimes:/,/chatNotif/p' home.html | sed '1s/.*lastActiveTimes://; $s/chatNotif.*//' > end.json
```

But did not work

Comment: try this and see it is correct: `perl -lne 'print $& if /(?<=lastActiveTimes:).*?(?=chatNotif)/g' home.txt`

Comment: @K-five You got it!, thanks!!! please add your question to mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do not mind using **Perl** you can try:

```
perl -lne 'print $& if /(?<=lastActiveTimes:).*?(?=,chatNotif)/g' home.txt
```

It prints anything between these two assertions:  `lastActiveTimes:` and `,chatNotif`

## or

```
ack -o '(?<=lastActiveTimes:).*?(?=,chatNotif)' home.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep and [Perl regular expression](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) (`-P`):

```
grep -Poz '(?<=lastActiveTimes:).*(\n.*)*(?=,chatNotif)' file
```

Output:

> {"707514313":1505610703,"1568212945":1505639008,"732898933":1505641310,"100009336847960":1505641325,"721251435":1505570865,"718844397":1505623246,"1461941075":1505501435,"100004389551456":1505637706,"1211838231":1505582601,"1040249145":1505639741,"1242203773":1505628782,"517814298":1505567030,"807572767":1505638510,"738307936":1505641007,"683874946":1505598251,"822469152":1505636589,"727476234":1505627000,"781209703":1505631577,"1058918804":1505629365,"539657070":1505629599,"1506662943":1505606109,"538279690":1505640516,"1122078957":1505633239,"1426504238":1505614371,"1760126206":1505637897,"100009494169236":1505633218,"100000193088625":1505633785,"628050112":1505599301,"692803720":1505641333,"100000982526361":1505611187,"1567918281":1505549275,"562061542":1505641305,"680188549":1505637979,"201400626":1505510516,"709905371":1505635235,"100000921265645":1505637511,"100002576634271":1505633420,"100001152648289":1505640582,"1580474418":1505583268,"1093906498":1505635647,"1568491642":1505638670,"1759941492":1505592915,"1021502749":1505621933,"100001091369712":1505593740,"1201111516":1505631603,"511729394":1505637150,"1228064980":1505627119,"1484357891":1505632720,"773982263":1505641308,"610763631":1505581711,"581839860":1505641241,"100001509228647":1505550106,"100001496847848":1505520708,"553024640":1505631903,"1657607627":1505460838,"100008134920032":1505636261,"518105631":1505610763,"100000167522595":1505559871,"604094302":1505591423,"831534764":1505498705,"716402163":1505625063,"100005862197805":1505615273,"779160397":1505625381,"683029723":1505602056,"1105801871":1505641175,"1007323327":1505640781,"500432034":1505617899,"1019441248":1505593648,"1321064988":1505549642,"600465009":1505557526,"734790522":1505614982,"1139898038":1505597330,"762749332":1505595541,"100006926654236":1505637009,"100007887856728":1505580453,"1073032118":1505602788,"575893114":1505630287,"1463373342":1505640415}